# Error="053 - NO PAGES" - Sita Web Services (SWS)

Tags: xml, web, service

I am using Sita Web Services (SWS).SWS is platform independent and is based on the OpenTravel™ Alliance (OTA) XML standards.
I had a problem that I encountered the following error when sending data airbook method.
Error="053 - NO PAGES"
If possible, please advise me well.
Thanks 
This is my xml request for AirBookRQ

```
    <OTA_AirBookRQ
Version="0"
xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
TransactionIdentifier="">
<POS><Source  AgentDutyCode = "xx" AgentSine = "xxx" AirlineVendorID = "xxx" AirportCode = "xxx" ERSP_UserID = "xxx"  ISOCountry = "xxx"  PseudoCityCode = "xxx"/></POS>
<AirItinerary>
<OriginDestinationOptions>
<OriginDestinationOption>
<FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2015-05-04T06:30:00">
<DepartureAirport LocationCode="TBZ"/>
<ArrivalAirport LocationCode="THR"/>
<OperatingAirline Code="I3" FlightNumber="5207"/>
<BookingClassAvails>
<BookingClassAvail
RPH="1"
ResBookDesigCode="P"
ResBookDesigStatusCode="1"
ResBookDesigQuantity="4"/>
</BookingClassAvails>
</FlightSegment>
</OriginDestinationOption>
</OriginDestinationOptions>
</AirItinerary>
<TPA_Extensions>
<GroupBooking
Name="Test"
NumOfSeats="1">
</GroupBooking>
</TPA_Extensions>
<TravelerInfo>
<AirTraveler
BirthDate="1985-04-19"
PassengerTypeCode="ADT">
<PersonName>
<NamePrefix>MR</NamePrefix>
<GivenName>Ali</GivenName>
<Surname>Ahmadi</Surname>
</PersonName>
<Telephone
PhoneNumber="914-444-4444"
PhoneTechType="1"
PhoneLocationType="7"
AreaCityCode="98"/>
<Telephone PhoneNumber="09121111111" PhoneTechType="5" FormattedInd="false" PhoneLocationType="7"/>
<Email>xxxx@gmail.com</Email>
<Address FormattedInd="false">
<AddressLine>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AddressLine>
</Address>
<PassengerTypeQuantity Quantity="1"/>
<TravelerRefNumber RPH="1"/>
</AirTraveler>
</TravelerInfo>
<Fulfillment>
<DeliveryAddress FormattedInd="false">
<AddressLine>xxxxxxxxxx</AddressLine>
</DeliveryAddress>
</Fulfillment>
<Ticketing TicketType="eTicket"/>
</OTA_AirBookRQ>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the xml definition line 1

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<OTA_AirBookRQ Version="0" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TransactionIdentifier="">
  <POS>
    <Source  AgentDutyCode = "xx" AgentSine = "xxx" AirlineVendorID = "xxx" AirportCode = "xxx" ERSP_UserID = "xxx"  ISOCountry = "xxx"  PseudoCityCode = "xxx"/>
  </POS>
  <AirItinerary>
    <OriginDestinationOptions>
      <OriginDestinationOption>
        <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2015-05-04T06:30:00">
          <DepartureAirport LocationCode="TBZ"/>
          <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="THR"/>
          <OperatingAirline Code="I3" FlightNumber="5207"/>
          <BookingClassAvails>
            <BookingClassAvail
            RPH="1"
            ResBookDesigCode="P"
            ResBookDesigStatusCode="1"
            ResBookDesigQuantity="4"/>
          </BookingClassAvails>
        </FlightSegment>
      </OriginDestinationOption>
    </OriginDestinationOptions>
  </AirItinerary>
  <TPA_Extensions>
    <GroupBooking
    Name="Test"
    NumOfSeats="1">
    </GroupBooking>
  </TPA_Extensions>
  <TravelerInfo>
    <AirTraveler
    BirthDate="1985-04-19"
    PassengerTypeCode="ADT">
      <PersonName>
        <NamePrefix>MR</NamePrefix>
        <GivenName>Ali</GivenName>
        <Surname>Ahmadi</Surname>
      </PersonName>
      <Telephone
      PhoneNumber="914-444-4444"
      PhoneTechType="1"
      PhoneLocationType="7"
      AreaCityCode="98"/>
      <Telephone PhoneNumber="09121111111" PhoneTechType="5" FormattedInd="false" PhoneLocationType="7"/>
      <Email>xxxx@gmail.com</Email>
      <Address FormattedInd="false">
        <AddressLine>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AddressLine>
      </Address>
      <PassengerTypeQuantity Quantity="1"/>
      <TravelerRefNumber RPH="1"/>
    </AirTraveler>
  </TravelerInfo>
  <Fulfillment>
    <DeliveryAddress FormattedInd="false">
      <AddressLine>xxxxxxxxxx</AddressLine>
    </DeliveryAddress>
  </Fulfillment>
  <Ticketing TicketType="eTicket"/>
</OTA_AirBookRQ>​
```